# Where is the message passed to Combine's `assertFatalError` printed?

Tags: xcode, combine

When a fatal error is triggered by [`assertFatalError(_file:line:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/assertnofailure(_:file:line:)) in a Combine pipeline, where is the message provided to its first argument printed?

I've got a pipeline that includes (e.g.):

```
.assertFatalError("Bad thing number 6 happened")
```

…but nowhere in the debug console (nor elsewhere in Xcode that I've yet found) am I seeing the string, "Bad thing number 6 happened" when this error is asserted. Just an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` that I wouldn't recognize out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this thread they're supposed to be in the crash log:

https://forums.swift.org/t/intercept-fatalerror-or-other-termination-messages-from-swift/6190

But they note:

> Unfortunately, it looks like iOS on-device prunes the application-specific info from crash logs because of user privacy concerns. The crash reason does show up in macOS or simulator crash logs, however.

There was further discussion in 2019 through to 2022 about making the messages easier to get to:

https://forums.swift.org/t/stdlib-cleanup-callback-for-fatal-swift-errors/26977/26

But I don't see any resolution

Comment: Oh, interesting… well it's at least somewhat sanity-inducing to know they are in fact difficult to get to. I wonder if there's something else I could be doing in code that would help debug failed `.assertNoFailure` integrity-checks…